# Tensors lose their dimensions during conversion from TF to TFlite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm converting a tensorflow model to tflite model (through python script) and although all input tensors are passed as input in the tflite some of them in tflite do not have any dimensions.

So in TF I have 5 input tensors (4D, 4D, 1D, 1D, 1D) and when I convert it to tflite I get 5 tensors (4D, 4D, 1D, 0D, 0D). I have no problem with the output tensors

I'm thinking something is happening inside `toco_tooling.cc` or some other file

some help?

Comment: Please add code that defines your model, and how you detected the 0D dimensions for your inputs.

Comment: Well regarding the model I cannot share anything as it's the company's proprietary code. What I can say is that it's created from a python script initially for TensorFlow and then inside the same script it's converted to tflite

Regarding the detection way, when my custom op is called (actually implementation, porting the operation from TF to tflite) the Prepare function is called.

I have a check like (sorry cannot format code & toolbar is missing):

`
    const auto inputTensor = GetInput(context, node, 3);
    TF_LITE_ENSURE_EQ(context, NumDimensions(inputTensor), 1);
`

Comment: You can reproduce this using a simpler toy example if you can't share proprietary code. Otherwise I wouldn't expect that you get answers to your question.